I'm trying to get accessibility working with a JavaFX application - what am I missing?
I have been tasked to add accessibility to a JavaFX application. I did all of the obvious things to get it to work: I added 'setAccessibleRole' definitions to each of the fields I wanted the screen reader to "speak", as well as tooltips for each field (some screen readers require it). According to the documentation, accessibility is supposed to be active the first time the screen reader software tries to interact with the program. But 'Platform.isAccessibilityActive()' always returns 'false' and I get no sound of any kind from the application.
So what am I missing? I don't see anything in any of the documentation indicating that something has to happen before the screen reader can work.
The screen reader software I am using is Orca. The application runs in a Linux environment running CentOS 7.
